# Appending two values as an array in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Im trying to have the user enter an x and y coordinate, which will then be stored in the dictionary 'p' in the form p = {0:[x,y], 1:[x,y], 2:[x,y], 3:[x,y]}. However I can only get either the x-value or the y-value stored in the dictionary for each key pair.

```
p = {}
for i in range(4):
    while True:
        p_input = input("Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:")
        p_components = p_input.split(',')
        if len(p_components) != 2:
            print("Missing coordinate please try again.")
            p_input = input("Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:")
        else:
            p[i] = float(p_components[0])
            p[i] = float(p_components[1])
            break
print(p)
```

For each key-value pair, how would I be able to store the x and y value as an array in the value part for each key?

Comment: `p[i] = [float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])]` ?

Comment: `p[i] = [float(component) for component in p_components]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use a dictionary if you are just using an integer index as the key—you could just use a list of lists. But as is, you could just do this in your final else block:

```
p[i] = []
p[i].append(float(p_components[0]))
p[i].append(float(p_components[1]))
```

Alternatively, just do:

```
p[i] = [float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])]
```

But I'd recommend just using a list instead of a dictionary, so something like:

```
p = []

for i in range(4):
    while True:
        p_input = input("Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:")
        p_components = p_input.split(',')
        if len(p_components) != 2:
            print("Missing coordinate please try again.")
            # redundant to print input again here as it will automatically loop and ask again
        else:
            p.append([float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])])
            break
print(p)
```

Comment: thank you, this is originally what I was trying to do, but I am quite new to programming :)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the dictionary's value when you do:

```
p[i] = float(p_components[0])
p[i] = float(p_components[1])
```

Try this instead:

```
p[i] = [float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])]
```

You can shrink your code a little bit, too, as the `while` is reduntant:

```
p = {}
for i in range(4):
    p_input = input("Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:")
    p_components = p_input.split(',')
    if len(p_components) != 2:
        print("Missing coordinate please try again.")
        p_input = input("Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:")
    else:
        p[i] = [float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
try:
    p[i] = [float(component) for component in p_components]
except:
    raise ValueError("INVALID_INPUT")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save the two converted coordinates to the one location `p[i]`, so you only ever get a single float added as a dict item, not a list of two floats. Actually, it's better to use a tuple for the coordinates (a coordinate pair is an ordered heterogeneous sequence, and a tuple consumes less RAM than a list).

Here's a repaired version of your code. I've added a little bit of extra error checking to ensure that the coords can be converted to floats.

```
p = {}
for i in range(4):
    while True:
        p_input = input("Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:")
        p_components = p_input.split(',')
        if len(p_components) != 2:
            print("Missing coordinate or too many coordinates, please try again.")
            continue
        try:
            x = float(p_components[0])
            y = float(p_components[1])
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid coordinates", p_components, "please try again.")
        else:
            p[i] = (x, y)
            break
print(p)
```

**demo output**

```
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:1,2
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:3,4,5
Missing coordinate or too many coordinates, please try again.
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:3
Missing coordinate or too many coordinates, please try again.
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:a,b
Invalid coordinates ['a', 'b'] please try again.
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates: 5  , 6
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:7,8
Enter starting point X,Y Coordinates:3,4
{0: (1.0, 2.0), 1: (5.0, 6.0), 2: (7.0, 8.0), 3: (3.0, 4.0)}
```

Comment: Nice, but why aren't you/we questioning the fact a dictionary is used with a range? (the structure is an array)

Comment: @AntonvBR Fair call. I'd normally use a list for something like this. Indexing is faster than dict lookup, and a list consumes less RAM than a dict. OTOH, a dict can be handy if you want to implement a sparse array, or even if you want a contiguous array with the first index being > 0. Also, if you want to create a bunch of points, and then drop the ones that fail some test it can be more efficient to do that with a dict.